# Google+ sign out from a different activity

Tags: android, api, google-api, android-activity, google-plus

I have started using the `Google+ API` for android, and I have created a sign-in application following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Now, the problem is that I want to create the sign out button from a different `Activity`, and what i tried to do didn't really worked..

My GPlusLogin code (Activity for the Google+ Login):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;

public class GPlusLogin extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "GPlusLogin";

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gplus_layout);
        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

        if(extras!=null){
            if(extras.getString("signout")!=null){
                if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                    mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
                    mPlusClient.disconnect();
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }
        }else{

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                        if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(GPlusLogin.this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                                // Try connecting again.
                                mConnectionResult = null;
                                mPlusClient.connect();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

        mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent main = new Intent(GPlusLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
        main.putExtra("result", true);
        startActivity(main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }

}
```

My Disconnect code on `MainActivity`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras==null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPlusLogin.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText("You Are Connected :D");

        Button SignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_gplus);
        SignOut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GPlusLogin.class);
                intent.putExtra("signout", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: how did you solve this problem? please share.

Comment: heres your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921515/sign-out-from-google-and-facebook-in-android-application/29336783#29336783
 
search my answer

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734567/separating-the-concerns-of-activity-and-googleapiclient/31734568#31734568

Answer (score 29):

Just add this on your new activity, where you want your logout-button for google+ to be there :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}
```

and next:

```
 signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                  new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onResult(Status status) {
                          // ...
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logged Out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                          startActivity(i);
                      }
                  });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Happy for you.@suraj :)

Comment: Google Play supports asynchronous sign in, so it is ok to sign out even if you are not sure if the sign in connected?

Answer (score 18):

Hey i solved this problem by myself, working like charm

What is the problem : Google plus signIn in one activity but need to Logout from another activity

### Solution:

My Google-plus Logout Activity is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
    ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {

   GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
   boolean mSignInClicked;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

     //copy this code on "Logout" Onclick
  logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            // updateUI(false);
            System.err.println("LOG OUT ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SUCESS");
        } 

        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSignInClicked = false;

    // updateUI(true);
    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(
            this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    // updateUI(false);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

### Description about solution:

For single package google plus API will generate one token & session.Just here simply make one more session in logout page also.You can easily logout from session now

I to have tried a lot about this problem,to logout from current session, just try this .it will definitely work. any doubts let me know

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help, its working fine. i struck last two days in this problem.

Comment: Hi @madhusudhan: I have following activities:
1. MainActivity: Displays the signing button will ask user to signin via GooglePlus account and redirects to the TabActivity.
2. TabActivity: Has the signout button.
Does the above solution involves creating one more activity and redirecting the user to it after clicking signout? Because I tried that way, but it looks like after I restart the application, I am being redirected to the TabActivity without being blocked by the MainActivity.

Answer (score 6):

It would probably be easier to create a base class and inherit the connect/disconnect methods. Photohunt, our full sample, documents this design in detail.

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/android#architecture_of_the_application)
[Code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-client-android/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/photohunt/BaseActivity.java)

Comment: For anyone finding this from Google (like me), the example code can now be found here https://github.com/vicfryzel/gplus-photohunt-client-android

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for over a week to find out the answer. 
I did this,
After signing in save boolean isSignedIn in sharedpreferences as true.

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.userDetails), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), true);
editor.apply();`
```

Now from any activity when the user clicks logout, change the boolean to false.

In your Login Activity where `googleApiClient` is build. In its onStart method.
Check if `isSignedIn` is false.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
if (!prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), false)) {
    signOut();
    }     
}
```

Do the same in `onConnected`

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: " + "yes it is connected");
        if (!prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), false)) {
            signOut();
        }
    }
}
```

This will logout and revokeAccess.

```
public void signOut() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "signOut: " + mGoogleApiClient + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            // ...
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + mGoogleApiClient);
                        }
                    });
         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: Revoke Access status:" + status.getStatus());
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get instance of FirebaseAuth  anywhere from the app as FirebaseAuth is a singleton class.

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 mAuth.signOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is correct that a base class or a fragment would make your life easier. That said, the code here could work - the problem is that you're checking whether the PlusClient is connected in `onCreate()` - but you don't connect it until `onStart()`. You'd probably need to check the intent in the `onConnected()` method, and perform the sign out there.

Comment: It is possible to create an observable state machine to represent the GoogleApiConnection, moving all code to outside the activity (or fragment). It might look Java over-engineering, but it allows coping/pasting the code in other projects. See http://goo.gl/L1CHaa

Answer (score 1):

Once you click logout from another activity,try send an intent with extra to indicate that logout button is clicked. Then on Login Activity

```
if (Intent.Extras != null && Intent.Extras.ContainsKey("LogoutAction")) {
    _logoutRequest = Intent.Extras.GetBoolean("LogoutAction");
}
if (_logoutRequest) {
    await PlusClass.AccountApi.RevokeAccessAndDisconnect(_apiClient);
    _apiClient.Disconnect();
    _apiClient.Connect ();
    _logoutRequest = false;
}
```

Other Activity

```
var intent = new Intent(this.Activity,typeof(LoginActivity));
intent.PutExtra("LogoutAction",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[sommesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5952645/sommesh)'s answer is perfect, but for less code you can use "Public Static Method" like this:

```
public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
...
...
public static void signOutFromGoogle() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    //...
                }
            });
}
```

And on your other Activity call it:

```
Your_Google_Activity.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {            
        Your_Google_Activity.signOutFromGoogle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I have made a `Utils` [singleton class](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples). In my `LoginActivity`, I have a `GoogleSignInClient` object. So just before starting the `DashboardActivity` after login, I save the instance of `googleSignInClient` object by calling `Utils.getInstance().setGoogleSignInClient(googleSignInClient)`. Now anywhere else, if I want to logout I have this method in `Utils` ready:

```
public void signOut() {
    googleSignInClient.signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
}
```

So now, I can do this from any other activity:

```
else if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
    Utils.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Yes, you need to log out from both of them, otherwise, you might not see the account chooser the next time you tap the login button.