# Sign Out From Google plus Account Not Working in android, Showing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using Google plus login in my android app its Working Fine.

While Clicking logout Button from any other intent Showing Null pointer Exception.

also While click login button directly going to my next page .not in sign in page.

but Logout from Demo Application Its working fine.

I Have searched  related  answers ,Not found any solution still remain same.

help me to resolve it

[link 1](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-plus-login-example/)

[link 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

I have referred 2 links but sign out from next intent still showing the Null pointer Exception.

My Logout Code:

```
public void googlePlusLogout() 
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) 
        {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateProfile(false);
        }

    }
```

here calling the method from other intent to signin class

otherintent.java

```
                  session.logoutUser();// here i am clearing the shared pref
                  sign_in Signinclass = new sign_in();
                  Signinclass.googlePlusLogout();
                  finish();
```

This is my demo code its working fine Same Code I Have used in my Application Login working fine ,but Logout calling from another page not working. Showing null pointer exception.

AndroidGooglePlusExample .java

```
public class AndroidGooglePlusExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    // Google client to communicate with Google
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean signedInUser;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private SignInButton signinButton;
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView username, emailLabel;
    private LinearLayout profileFrame, signinFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signinButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        emailLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

        profileFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.profileFrame);
        signinFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.signinFrame);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // store mConnectionResult
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (signedInUser) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                signedInUser = false;

            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        signedInUser = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
    }

    private void updateProfile(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                username.setText(personName);
                emailLabel.setText(email);

                new LoadProfileImage(image).execute(personPhotoUrl);

                // update profile frame with new info about Google Account
                // profile
                updateProfile(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateProfile(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signin:
            googlePlusLogin();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void signIn(View v) {
        googlePlusLogin();
    }

    public void logout(View v) {
        googlePlusLogout();
    }

    private void googlePlusLogin() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            signedInUser = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    private void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateProfile(false);
        }
    }

    // download Google Account profile image, to complete profile
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView downloadedImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView image) {
            this.downloadedImage = image;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            Bitmap icon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return icon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            downloadedImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code should work ..this is working for me ..can you post some more info so we can check where you are doing mistake

Comment: i am calling this method from other intent , not in sign in page. but i have tried demo app sign out from main activity its working fine

Comment: this can b work ..why dont u logout in other page ..oviously you will get null ponter exception for mGoogleApiClient...try to logout when u have login from gplus nd save your values in shared pref this worked for me

Comment: add some  code snippet for me. i have saved in shared pref only .while clicking logout button i am clearing the shared pref. but google plus account still not signed out

Comment: wait what i had done m sharing

Comment: check this   http://pastebin.com/jhcRmyXW

Comment: check my answer you will get idea

Comment: if u had done than mark it as accepted answer ..so anyone can take advantage of it

Comment: tried what you have suggested not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Solution for my Question

Add this Code in your Logout activity page. Its works perfectly

My Logout page activity

```
 public class LogoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {

       GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
       boolean mSignInClicked;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

         //copy this code on "Logout" Onclick
      logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                // updateUI(false);
                System.err.println("LOG OUT ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SUCESS");
            } 

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mSignInClicked = false;

        // updateUI(true);
        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        // updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

[link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29299190/4447803)